# How to use loop in where condtion in T-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select * from student where roll-no in (30 to 50)
```

`student` is table name, `roll_no, first_name, last_name, add` are columns

How to print student details whose roll no between 30 to 50?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a where clause with a range like:

```
 select * from student where [roll-no] >= 30 and [roll-no] <= 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from student 
 where roll-no between 30 and 50
```